# Deduce that $\Gamma(p)^{1/p}$ diverges as $p\rightarrow +\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, gamma-function

I was able to prove that if $f\in \bigcap_{p\ge 1}\textit{L}^p([0,1]) \setminus \textit{L}^{\infty}([0,1])$, then $||f||_p$ diverges as a function of $p$, said better: if we set $F(P):=||f||_p \longrightarrow +\infty$ as $p\rightarrow +\infty$.

Somebody suggested me that a nice application of this is: deduce that $\Gamma(p)^{1/p}$ diverges as $p\rightarrow +\infty$. Just to make it easyer if someone isnt sure about it, recall:
$$\Gamma(p)=\int_0^{+\infty}x^{p-1}e^{-x}dx \mbox{, when }p>0\mbox.$$

My attempt consisted in making substitutions to make sure we are on $[0,1]$ with the Gamma integral, and such that i could than overestimate the integral with the integral of a function $g$ in the set mentioned at the beninning so that the proof would finish with something like this:
$$\Gamma(P)^{1/p}\ge ||g||_p \longrightarrow \infty \mbox{, as } p\rightarrow +\infty\mbox,$$
thanks to the "lemma" at the beginning.

I'm hoping someone could give me some insight on what i could do better.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For a simpler approach, one could invoke Stirling's Formula.

Comment: How would you approach it this way tho? It would be cool.

Comment: $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k \ge  \sum_{k=n/2}^n \log  \frac{n}2$

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html ; in particular, equation 26 might be helpful

Comment: The substitution $u=e^{-x}$ gives $$\Gamma(p)=\int_{0}^{1}(-\log u)^{p-1}\,\mathrm{d}u,$$ hence $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\Gamma(p)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}=\lim_{p\to\infty}\|-\log u\|_{L^{p-1}([0,1],\mathrm{d}u)}=\infty.$$ This is enough to conclude that $\Gamma(p)^{1/p}$ also diverges to $\infty$.